# Cannot store value into global array SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xcode, api

I try to implement parsing XML from URL. I wrote two files:

MyXMLParser.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Order {
    var orderID: String!
    var productCode: String!
}


class MyXMLParser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate{
    private var orders = [Order]()
    private var currentElement: String = ""
    private var currentID: String = "" {
        didSet {
            currentID = currentID.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }

    private var currentProdCode: String = "" {
        didSet {
            currentProdCode = currentProdCode.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }
    private var parserCompletionHandler: (([Order]) -> Void)?


    func parseFeed(stringURL: String, completionHandler: (([Order]) -> Void)?) {
        self.parserCompletionHandler = completionHandler

        if let encodedString = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let validURL = URL(string: encodedString)
        {
            let request = URLRequest(url: validURL)
            let urlSession = URLSession.shared
            let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, responds, error) in
                if let validData = data
                {
                    //parse XML Data
                    let parser = XMLParser(data: validData)
                    parser.delegate = self
                    parser.parse()
                }
                else
                {
                    print("do not have data received")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
        else
        {
            print("unable to create url")
        }


    }



    // MARK: - XML Parser functions

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        currentElement = elementName
        if currentElement == "Orders"{
            currentID = ""
            currentProdCode = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        switch currentElement {
        case "OrderID":
            if currentID == "" {
                currentID += string
            }
        case "ProductCode":
            currentProdCode += string
        default:
            break
        }

    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "Orders" {
            let order = Order(orderID: currentID, productCode: currentProdCode)
            self.orders.append(order)
        }

    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        parserCompletionHandler?(orders)
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        print("Error when parsing Falcon XML, \(parseError.localizedDescription) ")
    }


}
```

The table view controller swift file is:

```
import UIKit



class XMLTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    private let testURL = "http://www.XXXX.com/....."
    var orders = [Order]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchData()
        print("test3:", self.orders)
    }


    func fetchData(){
        let myParser = MyXMLParser()
        myParser.parseFeed(stringURL: testURL) { (orders) in

            print("test1: ", orders)
            self.orders = orders
            print("test2: ", self.orders)


            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .left)
            }
        }

        print("test:", self.orders)

    }





    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
```

On the console:

```
test: []
test3: []
test1:  [XXXXXXX.Order(orderID: Optional("8963"), productCode: Optional("182SLD-UFPLP-B"))]
test2:  [XXXXXXX.Order(orderID: Optional("8963"), productCode: Optional("182SLD-UFPLP-B"))]
```

I am confused that since I have written that "`self.orders = orders`" and test1, test2 shows that there is data in local variable "orders" , why the global variable orders is empty?
 Please help me out, Thank you so much and I appreciate it.

Comment: Your `parseFeed` method includes data tasks which run _asynchronously_. `self.orders` is not populated until your http request has received a response. you can already see by the console output that your completion handler does not get called until _after_ the other two print statements already executed indicating that `parseFeed` is an asynchronous method

Comment: I want to store the data and populate the data on the table view cell. Please tell me how I can store data in global array? Thank you

Comment: It is being stored the `self.orders` array, but not until test1 is printed

Comment: I still don't know how to avoid the "asynchronously" problem. Could you please give more hint in detail? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The value of `self.orders` is being populated after the asynchronous HTTP request is completed. If you want your data to populate properly in the table view you need to modify your code to include the following:

```swift
class OrderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}

class XMLTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    private let testURL = "http://www.XXXX.com/....."
    var orders = [Order]() {
        didSet { tableView?.reloadData() }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView?.register(OrderTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "default")
        fetchData()
        print("test3:", self.orders)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return orders.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = orders[indexPath.row].orderID
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = orders[indexPath.row].productCode
        return cell
    }

    func fetchData(){
        let myParser = MyXMLParser()
        myParser.parseFeed(stringURL: testURL) { (orders) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("test1: ", orders)
                self.orders = orders
                print("test2: ", self.orders)
            }
        }
        print("test:", self.orders)
    }

}
```

Comment: my pleasure. feel free to upvote my answer and mark it correct

Comment: OK , No problem, Thank you

Comment: I try to use the new code you just updated. The table view cell only show the orderID no ProductCode. Why this happened?

Comment: @DellLin you need to create your own class that extends `UITableViewCell` and register that

Comment: What do the two functions in class "OrderTableViewCell" do?

Comment: they are initializers. One is required and the other overrides the display style of the `UITableViewCell`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/cellstyle)

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: If you want to make a custom table view cell you will want to override the `draw(_ rect:)` method where you can add labels and other kinds of `UIView` objects or even apply advanced graphics using the Core Graphics framework.

Comment: @DellLin feel free to upvote and mark this answer correct now that enough time has elapsed for you as a new user. Also, welcome to StackOverflow